# JPA class Person with field children

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a database entity Person with these fields:

1. id
2. father
3. mother

And that I need create the JPA Entity class with field children.
Something like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "father")
    private Integer fatherID;

    @Column(name = "mother")
    private Integer motherID;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fatherId")
    private List<Person> children;
    }
```

But problem is that I need to determine mother also in `mappedBy` attribute. The result might look like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM person WHERE father = id OR mother = id
```

Can somebody help me with this issue? Is this task possible at all using JPA?

Comment: Very interesting to solve the problem by clean JPA annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from mapping issues that have been pointed out...

Not a JPA expert but I don't think JPA has this case considered directly. I would solve this using two mappings and an auxiliar fake getter. Sample below:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "father")
private List<Person> childrenIfFather();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mother")
private List<Person> childrenIfMother();

public getChildren() {
    if (childrenIfFather != null) return childrenIfFather();
    else return childrenIfMother();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't Vote Up, because I got message 'Vote Up requires 15 reputation':-) Your solution takes place to be. Although it may affect a performance issues. But from me +1. For now it's best way.. And also  I would like to create a completely clean Entities without any logic. All logic will be placed in the Service layer.

Comment: Well, implement it and if it really suits you, I think you should still be able to mark the answer as correct later. In this case the logic of selecting a list or another is logic related to the way classes are being persisted so I'd personally put it in the `Person` entity rather that in a service layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have "mappedBy" to a non-object type (since that is not a **bidirectional** relation). You have to have "mother" and "father" fields of type Person (not Integer) to have a bidir relation. Getting the father and mother is then trivial

Comment: yes, you're right mappedBy I can't use, because it's not bidirectional relationship... And yes, I have father and mother as Person type, but my problem is in children field (therefore I have removed this code from the example).

Person somePerson = personService.getPerson(1);
List<Person> children = somePerson.getChildren();

Comment: Hibernate implements JPA. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796459/hibernate-onetoone-relationship/12796541#comment17302705_12796541

Comment: Who said Hibernate didn't implement JPA? There are many implementations of JPA (of which DataNucleus JPA is also one). My answer was to the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using EJBQL (or is it JPQL at this point?) to solve it:

```
  SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.father = ?1 OR p.mother = ?2
```

Also, I'd consider using something that isn't an Integer for the id. It can really bite you in the long run (maybe a long or BigInteger).

Comment: Yes, JPQL as variant. Do you mean create a method in DAO like getChildren(long personId); and as body of this method something like entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.father = ?1 OR p.mother = ?2", Person.class) ?

Comment: @George You wouldn't need to do a native query, JPQL can handle a query like this returning all the "Person" objects that match. I think you're looking to make this significantly more complex than it is. I'd definitely use a DAO/Service and forgo using an Entity that contains it. It feels like a mess to maintain when the relationship is so easy.