# Hibernate OneToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have two persistence entity: `User` and `UserDetail`. They have one-to-one relationship. I use hibernate annotations. But I am getting in my database several objects of user information for one same user. Apparently my knowledge of Hibernate annotations are not so good to solve this problem.

**User** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Long id; 

   @Column(name = "NAME")
   private String name; 

   @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
   private String password;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private UserDetail userDetail;

   // setters and getters

}
```

**UserDetail** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAIL")
public class UserDetail {  

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
   private User user;

   // other fields

}
```

I use this in my code as follows:

```
UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
userDetail.setInfo(info);
userDetail.setUser(seventhUser);
hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(userDetail);
```

And everything works properly. Here's what my table `USER_DETAIL`:
[image: USER_DETAIL table]

But when I try to change user information, I get an incorrect behavior. I get following table after I again set user information:

```
UserDetail newUserDetail = new UserDetail();
newUserDetail.setInfo(newInfo);
newUserDetail.setUser(seventhUser);
hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(newUserDetail);
```

[image]

Why the same two objects of information correspond to one user?? I have One-To-One relationship. How can I avoid this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify an existing `UserDetail`, then you must set its ID, or get it from the session and modify it. Else, Hibernate thinks it's a new one that must be saved, since it doesn't have any ID.

```
UserDetail existingUserDetail = session.get(UserDetail.class, theUserDetailId);
existingUserDetail.setInfo(newInfo);
```

To make sure you don't save two UserDetail instances for the same user, you should add a unique constraint on the `USER_ID` column of the `UserDetail` database table.

Comment: I can somehow get Hibernate to check consistency of the data at the database level? That there not was such situation that several objects are related to one user but with one-to-one relationship

Comment: *To make sure you don't save two UserDetail instances for the same user, you should add a unique constraint on the USER_ID column of the UserDetail database table*